# how to truncate text,android

Tags: android

I have a string headerText, which containing text "ABC (2-8 Days)".
How can truncate text after "("?
I just need text as ABC only not anything after "(" and before ")"

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
String truncText = CurrentString.split("(")[0];
```

I'm unfamiliar with Java so you may wind up needing to do this instead:

```
String[] separated = CurrentString.split("(");
String truncText = seperated[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with replace regex:

```
String justABC = "ABC (2-8 Days)".replaceAll("\\(.*\\)","()");
```

The first argument of `.replaceAll` says that we going to match to (*anything*) and the second that you want to replace match with just brackets. Doubleslashes here to escape brackets.